# Accessing a controller through a PhaseListener

Tags: java, jsf-2

I wrote a PhaseListener and would like to know if it is possible to access a controller through it.

Comment: but why you want to do this ?

Comment: You want a handle to the `FacesServlet`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can evaluate an EL expression programmatically by [`Application#evaluateExpressionGet()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/Application.html#evaluateExpressionGet%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%29). Wrap this in a convenience method like follows:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> T findBean(String beanName) {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    return (T) context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{" + beanName + "}", Object.class);
}
```

Use it in your JSF code as follows:

```
MyBackingBean myManagedBean = JSF.findBean("myManagedBeanName");
// ...
```